# How to add value to field according to other fields by using where condition in QGIS3.0?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a dictionary created from python. I want to update my attribute table accroding to that dictionary in QGIS3.0:

dict = {1:4, 2:5, 3:8, 4:9, 5:12, 6:17}

I want to see that values according to something like this condition:

```
UPDATE su_kutlesi = 1 WHERE Subbasin = 4
UPDATE su_kutlesi = 2 WHERE Subbasin = 5
UPDATE su_kutlesi = 3 WHERE Subbasin = 8
UPDATE su_kutlesi = 4 WHERE Subbasin = 9
UPDATE su_kutlesi = 5 WHERE Subbasin = 12
UPDATE su_kutlesi = 6 WHERE Subbasin = 17
```

I looked `CASE` from `conditionals` in `qgis:fieldcalculator`. It seems okey for me but I can not use that. Also, I do not want to insert loop my code but if neccessary, it is okey.Here is my attribute table:

[image]

Comment: You are using ; when you should use : in the Dictionary, for example `d = {1:2, 3:4}`

Comment: Can you clarify on "It seems okey for me but I can not use that."

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn I think it will work for my problem but I can not use it. Maybe it does not work... As I said, I can not use it at the end of the day.

Comment: "Can not use it" is very unspecific, is it a technical or political restriction you are experiencing? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using pyqgis, I mean you are working with qgis from python console then you can do something like this

```
lyr=iface.activeLayer()
su_kutlesi_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6] 
Subbasin_list=[4,5,8,9,12,17]
lyr.startEditing()
for idx,sub in enumerate(Subbasin_list):
    featItr =lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression("\"Subbasin\"='{}'".format(sub))))
    feat = [f for f in featItr]
    feat = feat[0]
    fldIdx = feat.fieldNameIndex("su_kutlesi")
    lyr.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(),fldIdx,su_kutlesi_list[idx])
lyr.commitChanges()
```

Hope this answers your question.
Note: this works for QGIS 3.x only

Comment: It works for me thank you @AsadAbbas. But you made a little mistake in your answer. It should be feat.id() instead of feat.id

Answer (score 1):

You can update the field su_kutlesi using Field Calculator as follows:

1. Select Field Calculator
2. Select `Update Existing field`
3. Choose `su_kutlesi` field from the menu list

[image]

4. Use the the following formula:

   ```
   CASE
   WHEN Subbasin = 4 Then 1
   WHEN Subbasin = 5 Then 2
   WHEN Subbasin = 8 Then 3
   WHEN Subbasin = 9 Then 4
   WHEN Subbasin = 12 Then 5
   WHEN Subbasin = 17 Then 6
   END
   ```

The result is shown in blue color.

Tested on QGIS 3.0.1